# How do you research weapons?

Tags: mass-effect-2

Where on the normandy do you upgrade weapons? Main dock?

Comment: Do you mean upgrade your guns or upgrade the weapons on the Normandy?

Comment: Well assuming his question I think he wants to know where he can upgrade his weapons at the Normandy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take a look at this [wiki article](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Research).

It points you to this information:

> The research terminal is located in the Normandy's Tech Lab on the CIC Deck (Deck 2) and Mordin must be recruited before the player can gain access to the lab.

Hopefully you find it with these information. :-)